# Cloudfront not serving content over http2

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, http2

I have a website hosted via S3 and served through Cloudfront. The web requests I see coming from my domain are all served over http1.1 and not http2, even though it is checked (by default!). Are there additional tasks I need to do to be able to see my content being served using http2?

I can see in the network tab in Chrome that some assets are being loaded via http2 (resources that do not come from my Cloudfront) but everything being loaded from my Cloudfront is http1.1

[image: Screenshot of network tab]

**Update 2**
It seems as though other users are seeing my site loaded over http2 correctly, and I tried using Firefox, and see the same results. So this is a Chrome issue, not a Cloudfront issue.

Comment: How are you checking? Is the client you're accessing it with capable of HTTP2?

Comment: I'm using Chrome to test, using network tab. I've updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: I see this in my Network panel in Chrome; everything's HTTP2: https://imgur.com/JRKw0vm

Comment: https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test also indicates you've got it up and running.

Answer (score 1):

This was not an issue with Cloudfront, instead I think it was combination of antivirus, network firewall/VPN, and Chrome caching. I turned off all VPN, antivirus, cleared cache in Chrome, restarted my computer and Bam! Page loads over HTTP2